# How to connect a Spark Streaming POST request to Node.js/Socket.io

Tags: node.js, socket.io, spark-streaming

first of all I'm very new to this topic - so apologies in advance if my question leaves room for interpretation,

I want to connect spark streaming data via POST to my Node.js server running Socket.io which then should pass the data in real-time to a frontend.

I [tried this tutorial](https://scotch.io/tutorials/build-a-restful-api-using-node-and-express-4) and in parallel tested a first connection to socket.io with a small example. But how can I connect the two sides.

In detail: Getting Spark Streaming Data as JSON and providing it to a D3 Frontend via Socket.io.

Thank you so much for your support.

Best regards,
ZB

Comment: I am sure it must be a way to connect Node.js some how to Spark both source/output but have you tried ZeroMQ as intermediate? It is really fast and super easy to setup. In fact I can't call it setup. It's just a library that you install and super easy to make it work in Node.js. But I understand if someone wants to eliminate unnecessary technologies in the middle if it was possible.